# Stream multiple mp4 files one after another via HTTP

Tags: python, http, video, stream, fastapi

Trying to read multiple mp4 files and stream them concatenated one after another via the same HTTP endpoint using FastAPI's StreamingResponse. However both approaches don't yield the desired result. I think I need to yield each mp4 as atomic chunks instead of entire file? Any ideas?

server.py

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import os
import cv2

app = FastAPI()


# PROBLEM: Stops after first mp4 played
def read_multiple_files_as_one():
    for file_name in os.listdir('./examples'):
        if file_name.endswith(".mp4"):
            with open('./examples/' + file_name, 'rb') as f_in:
                # video = f_in.read()
                yield from f_in

@app.get("/video")
async def main():
    return StreamingResponse(read_multiple_files_as_one(), media_type="video/mp4")


# PROBLEM: Wrong frame rate
# PROBLEM: No sound
def read_multiple_files_as_one_2():
    count = 0
    for file_name in os.listdir('./examples'):
        if file_name.endswith(".mp4"):
            cam = cv2.VideoCapture(
                './examples/' + file_name)

            while True:
                success, frame = cam.read()
                if not success:
                    break
                else:
                    ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                    frame = buffer.tobytes()

                    count +=1
                    # print(f'frame #: {count}')

                    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                        b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.get("/video2")
async def main():
    return StreamingResponse(read_multiple_files_as_one_2(), media_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <video width="1280" height="720" autoplay controls muted>
      <source src="http://localhost:8000/video" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>

    <img src="http://localhost:8000/video2" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would guess the issue is that you are trying to create one mp4 file by just concatenating them as byte strings, and that's not how mp4 works (I don't know the format exactly, but there is probably a lot of metadata, headers, it might be compressed). I would recommend looking into something like [`moviepy`](https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/) that uses FFMpeg.

Comment: @M.O. I checked moviepy but doubt it supports stitching mp4s on the fly… As all the files will have mostly same metadata I think I just need to understand better how <video> tag is reading the response and then concatenate the mdat boxes/containers of the mp4 files. Just can‘t find anything about this online

Comment: @anthnyprschka You need to fragment your MP4s and make sure they all have the same encoder settings (same resolution, same profile _eg:_ Main). A fragmented MP4 has a main header with the MOOV atom, then followed by the video chunks themselves with their own MOOF headers. You concat by first sending the bytes of the main MOOV chunk (along with other related atoms like FTYP) then from there you can feed in a sequence of chunks. Where a chunk is either a full length MP4 or smaller sections of the MP4. **(1)** Use FFmpeg (if possible) to create test files. **(2)** Use a hex-editor to check bytes.

Comment: @anthnyprschka PS: If your MP4s are not fragmented then you could still workarounfd that by reading the required bytes out of MP4 and packaging them in a MOOF-based chunk whose bytes (header) are dynamically created by code followed by the MP4 data..

Comment: @VC.One thanks for the inputs, I started parsing the mp4s now using python struct package and also saved them as fmp4. However when i just use ftyp and moov from first file and moof and mdat from all files and save to file it messes up the tracks (first plays video then audio or so). I need to dig deeper and try to provide more info when i’m back at the computer

Comment: Quick update i‘ve concatenated 2 files using ffmpeg with -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov which plays fine compared to my script. In MP4 Inspector the file looks almost the same as the file from script though (check here: https://imgur.com/a/ET5DLsO) but it‘s not exactly the same. I guess I need to find the exact differences and fix them in my script..